# Unable to move focus using Action class in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, action

[image]Hello I am working with popup which are made by 
So while I click on one button i.e. "click1" it pops up one div window ..
So on this pop up I can play with element by using action class

```
WebElement element = wd.findElement(By.className("qx-window"));
Actions actions = new Actions(wd);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

Now from this popup while i click on another button it again pops up another popup and again I tried with action class but unable to set focus on the new pop up

So scenario is main window->popup->popup

can I able to remove focus from first pop up

Hear below selenium code is not working that's why I use action

```
for (String popup : wd.getWindowHandles())
{
wd.switchTo().window(popup);
}
```

Comment: Share screenshot for opened popups as well

Comment: Hello Saurabh because of privacy I am not able to provide you real screen shot but i try to make sample template.... hope it will provide you the use full information

Comment: All of these popups open in new window or same window??

Comment: New Window....
which is made by <div>..... I tried with

Comment: Error Log : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (960, 483). Other element would receive the click: <div style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;touch-action:none;-ms-touch-action:none;box-sizing:border-box;position:absolute;-moz-user-select:none;cursor:default;background-color:#c7dcef;left:0px;top:0px;width:578px;height:417px;" qxselectable="off"></div> (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds

Comment: Try to click on element using `JavascriptExecutor` then as `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element)` and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try with below flow

```
        //Store main window handle in one variable
        String mainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

        //click something on window to open popup1
        Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles(); //It returns Set of available window handles

        //from above set get popup1 handle and switch control to popup1
        //==switch control to pop-up1
        windowHandles.remove(mainWindowHandle);
        String popup1Handle=(String)windowHandles.toArray()[0];
        driver.switchTo().window(popup1Handle);

        //do your operations in popup1
        //===== YOUR ACTIONS GOES HERE FOR POPUP1

        //click on button in popup1 which will open popup2

        //switch the control to popup2
        windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles(); //It returns Set of available window handles, here it returns 3 window handles
        windowHandles.remove(mainWindowHandle);
        windowHandles.remove(popup1Handle);
        String popup2Handle=(String)windowHandles.toArray()[0];
        driver.switchTo().window(popup2Handle);
        //do your operations in popup2
        //===== YOUR ACTIONS GOES HERE FOR POPUP2


        driver.close(); // this will close popup2 as control is in popup2

        //switch the control to main window again
        driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle);
```

Comment: Thanks but this code won't works as the pop up is made by <div> and I already try above code .....  the error is in SET it only stores current window ID adn the pop up are made with div TAG...

Comment: Then it is not an new window. So try to locate element with respect to that parent div locator. Example: By.cssSelector("div[id='popup1'] input[type='button']")

Comment: I tried but ... i want to use two argument for one div i.e. class name as well as tabindex. so how can we achieve in cssSelector
suppose<div class_name = design_highlighted and tabindex=4>
So how can we use these both ....?

Comment: You can achieve that by specifying like this==>  By.cssSelector("div[class-'design_highlighted'][tabindex='4']")